# Multiwii GUI on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: opengl-es, processing, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi2, jogl

I've been trying to get the Multiwii gui to compile on a Raspberry Pi 3, using Processing version 2.2.1. The libraries are good, everything seems fine, except that when I try to run the thing it says Java awt class cast exception. I've did my bit of homework, after spending days of research online, I've noticed three explanations for this.

1. Open GL and AWT compatibility on the Raspberry Pi is not supported
2. I need to use NEWT
3. I needed to use other rendering code for P3D

Despite doing everything I could, things don't seem to fall in place. I've read guides about using jogl native window libraries, tried the part, failed. I tried using glw library which was suggested, failed.  There seems to be no proper solution online, just a lot of outdated ones.

Also, using Processing 3 doesn't help either. I just get an error that says couldn't compile open GL vertex shader with a dialog that reads that another cryptic error message I can make no sense of.

I'm already out of my limit, anyone with any help and a decent kind set by step help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: The reason I want to get this done is to be able to build a Pi Copter. I'm following the one which uses R Pi as the receiver and an Android phone as a transmitter, using the Multiwiii FC. Any help on this topic would be appreciated, too.